# How to display rows with data same of the displayed row

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a table similar to:
product_id - code - name - img - ...

I've made a page to display all the products.
Once you click on one, you go to that product's detail page.
    ">

In the first part of the details page there are all the data referring to the selected code
and this is working right.

```
$var1_getProduct = "unavailable";
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
$var1_getProduct = $_GET['code'];
}
...
$query_getProduct = sprintf("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.code = %s", GetSQLValueString($var1_getProduct, "text"));
```

In the bottom of the page I'd like to display all the other products that have same name.
I made similar tril, but no one seems to work and I don't understand how should I deal with this...

Should I made a different query? I tried but didn't work...
    $query_getProducts = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.code = getProducts['code']"

Or should I try to Join the table on itself, like if are 2 different table ? Also this didn't work...
    $query_getProducts = "SELECT  t2.name FROM    `product` t1 JOIN    `product` t2 ON (t2.name = t1.name) WHERE   t1.name = '$name' AND t1.name != '0'";

The problem being I don't know how to achieve the result I need, I mean the way to reach (and also the code..., but that will be a different problem!)

EDIT
I didn't mention the solution i found that is more near to what i need, that is:

```
SELECT product.name
FROM product 
INNER JOIN ( 
SELECT product.name
FROM product
WHERE product.code = var1 
) pname ON pname.name = product.name
```

the problem with this, is that it show all the products with that name, including the active one. So I'm also not able to put an IF 'product with same name exist' Echo the parent DIV...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `code` is a unique key for your product. Well, first I guess you get the name of the product already in the result of your first statement, so maybe you can reuse it in the second query as something like `select * from product where name='%s' and code!='%s'`. If you cannot do this, fetching the name in a subquery might work, like:

```
select * from product 
    where name = (select name from product where code='%s')
    and code != '%s';
```

if you get more than one result from the `select name from product where code='%s'` then maybe use `where name in (select name from product where code='%s')` but then my assumption that `code` identifies the product is wrong and this solution might not work at all.

Comment: Many thanks Clemens!
That was exactly what I was looking for!
Actually yes, code is unique key.
But what about name, if there is more than one name stated with a comma in the middle in the database record? because like this didn't show me the records with more than one name..

Comment: Uhm, so the `name` field actually contains several names, comma separated? I feel you might better rethinking the data structure, e.g. keeping the different names in a separate table referencing the product. Then alternatively with the current structure you can try to match word boundaries in the select like `SELECT * FROM product WHERE name REGEXP '[[:<:]]%s[[:>:]]' and code !='%s'` as explained in the mySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html . As the original name might contains commas to, you might have to fetch it and split it first.